# Does some convention govern which companies report earnings in the morning vs. evening?

Tags: corporate-earnings

Most companies report after market close, but some (10%? 30%?) report in the morning. What rules control when some do it in the morning vs.  evening? 
 Please answer separately, if necessary, for Canada, US, and Europe (I won't specify the major markets).

Answer (score 2):

In the US, companies with a public float of at least $75 million  must file earnings reports within 35 days of the end of the  first three quarters and both quarterly and annual reports no more than 60 days after the end of their fiscal year.  They are free to report at any time of the day, including during market hours.

Comment: would it be safe to say that most report after hours so as to reduce the volatility (during market hours) of their stock?

Comment: More companies report PM than AM but if you consider both to be 'after hours' then yes, they report then to reduce trading disruption  in their stock.  It gives investors and traders more time to interpret the information, thereby reducing volatility. Decades ago, PM EA's were more frequent because the world wasn't as connected as it is now with the web. Some companies with bad news scheduled release on days with the most releases, trying to hide among the masses. Some offering really bad news even released on Friday afternoon with the hope that the weekend would soften the effect of it.

Comment: well i know AM can be pre-market, but it would seem more companies report PM to allow the longer overnight period to, as you say, soften the effect.